# Elliptic curves over a finite field represented as winding it around a torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I have an elliptic curve $E$ in the form $ y ^ 2 = 4x^3 - a x - b $ and a prime number $p$. Now I want to find the integer $(x,y)$ pairs which satisfies the equation $$mod(y ^ 2,p) =mod(4x^3 - a x - b,p)$$
I can see, if I find all the points which are located in the domain $0<=x,y<p$, and I have a solution $(x_1,y_1)$ I can generate easily infinitely many of the solutions just by adding to them the product of $p$ and an integer like: $(x_1+np,y_1+mp)$. Due to this property, I've heard, this domain could be represented as a torus. My question is that, if I start to wind up my original $E$ around this torus (formed by the "base" domain), does $E$ eventually go through all the $(x,y)$ solution pairs? There is a link to the video which made me to think about this question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFVKuFZ29Fc

Answer (score 4):

Let have an Elliptic Curve over a finite field $K = \mathbb{F}_q$ then the curve is defined as

$$E(\mathbb{K}) := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{K}^2 \mid y^2+a_1xy+a_3y = x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6\} \cup \{\mathcal O\}$$

What is $\{\mathcal O\}$, it is the point of infinity and has no geometric picture and in the algebraic construction, we magically add one with no coordinates.

**Bounds on the number of points**

Now, if the characteristic is not equal to 2 or 3, then we have the short Weierstrass Equation

$$y ^ 2 = 4x^3 - a x - b $$

As we can see from the algebraic definition we can have at most $q^2+1$ point on the curve (not infinitely many). If you assume that $q$ is a prime (not a prime power) and $4x^3 - a x - b $ attains all $q$ values, then by the [quadratic residue theorem on primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus), we already know $(p - 1)/2$ of the elements are Quadratic NonResideu, so they are not a solution to the curve equation, i.e. $y^2= a$ has no solution.

For the bound of the number of points we have [Hasse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves)

$$|N - (q+1)| \le 2 \sqrt{q}$$

**How to find the exact number of points**

To calculate the exact number of points we can use

- [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm), René Schoof, 1985 with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\log^8 q)$, or improved version;
- [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin algorithm (SEA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\log^6 q)$

In Sagemath calling `E.cardinality()` is enough to get the number of points.

**How to represent the curves over a finite field**

In the finite case, we have a discrete plot

[image]

This is the plot of curve $E \colon y^2=x^3+4x+20$ over $\mathbb{F}_{29}$ with 37 points. Notice the symmetry $y,-y$!. In this image there is no representation of the $\mathcal{O}$, it can be represented in projective coordinates.

**Point addition**

[image]

Notice the red line passing through $P$ and $Q$ and the third point and the reflected point $ R = P + Q$.

**Mapping curve to Torus**

Any rectangle can be mapped into a torus with some [stretches](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Torus_from_rectangle.gif/220px-Torus_from_rectangle.gif).

[image]

To better view this image use the interactive HTML version, you can zoom and rotate in 3D, you can [download it from Github](https://github.com/kelalaka153/Torus-Ray-Tracing) and view it locally. You can also see the mapping method on the code.